# Right align columns of text inside flex rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a grid in flexbox and due to border issues and padding I've come up with the below html structure

https://jsfiddle.net/rqmdxcjo/

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex w-40">
    <h3 class="pr-6 py-0.5">Row A</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="flex w-25 border-right">
    <div class="py-0.5 px-6">AAA</div>
    <div class="py-0.5 px-6">AAA</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex w-25 border-right">
    <div class="py-0.5 px-6">AAA</div>
    <div class="py-0.5 px-6">AAA</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex w-10">
    <div class="pl-6 py-0.5">AAAA</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works out great and shows as

> Row --------- AAA AAA | AAA AAA | AAA

The only problem arises when you have different length string, in this example AAA vs AAAA vs AAAA. In the picture and fiddle you'll see on these lines the text stays left aligned. I am trying to right-align that text but keep everything else the same. I've tried applying float: right and text-align: right at various spots to no avail.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/rqmdxcjo/

How can I right align the test in these cells while maintaining padding and border position?

Comment: This looks like it should be a table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, you want to right align the divs that contain text, AAA, AAAA, etc. It doesn't work with your existing code, because these divs are only as big as their content. So even though `text-algn: right;` is applied to them, they are only as big as "AAAA" and it doesn't look like they are right aligned.
Give these divs some width using:

```css
.flex.border-right div {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

I'm targeting these divs using `.flex.border-right div`, but you can add your own class if needed.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72h6nemk/1/)